# create a nested dict in parallel

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I need to create a dict which looks like this:

```
variables = {}
variables['throttle'] = {
    (e, i, h, t): xp.var(lb=0, vartype=xp.continuous)
                         for e in engine_list
                         for i in max_num_engine
                         for h in temp_levels
                         for t in all_timesteps
}
variables['flow'] = ...
```

where len(timesteps) is 16000 and the others are somewhere between 3-5 long. I know I can make this with numpy as matrix and that would be much faster, but I need the dictionary structure for later (to process the solution). `xp` is the xpress package, a commercial solver (with atrocious python support and functionality and documentation)

The dict comprehension takes about 0.5 - 3 seconds and I need to do 60-100 of them (not all this big) can I somehow spawn multiple processes to create a bunch of these dicts in parallel and then merge them? What would be the best method to do this? Each key is is slightly different so I don't loop over their creation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the only thing you can optimize is call to `xp.var`. Comprehension itself (for this amount of data) take ~200ms on mediocre core (but always good to profile this).

Only way I can see here, is to speed-up `xp.var`. I can not test this locally, but check if you can create `xp.var(lb=0, vartype=xp.continuous)` and clone it in comprehension, instead of external call.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I figured too. `xp.var` is out of my control though. It is more about spawning a bunch of processes that do different tasks (different dict comprehensions)  but return to a  common result (the dict `variables`).